# How to write this score_function in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get some document order by custom score function:

```
day(now - document.create_time)  * 10 + length(document.content) + document.answer_count
```

how can I write this score function in elasticsearch?

of cause

my document has field:

`create_time
content
answer_count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assuming that :

- create_time -> @timestamp, string type
- content -> string type
- answer_count -> numeric type

You can write this score function in Elasticsearch like below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match_all": {}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "script_score": {
                "script": "((System.currentTimeMillis() - doc['@timestamp'].value.toLong() ) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) * 10 + doc['content'].value.length() + doc['answer_count'].value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you should adapt the part of convert:

```
((System.currentTimeMillis() - doc['@timestamp'].value.toLong() ) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
```

PS: I used groovy Language in script section.
Remember to activate the mode ElasticSearch script in the configuration file **config/elasticsearch.yml**:

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

Regards,
Alain

Comment: it also need to add 'boost_mode' => 'replace',